# React - provider for reusable hooks/functions that depend on child props?

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if the question title is unclear, I'm not totally sure how to phrase what I'm asking for. I have the below setup:

```
function useParams(attributes, pieceOfState) {
    //Do some hook logic here and return updated params
}

function setParam(name, param, attributes, pieceOfState){
    //Do some logic that sets the parameter
}

export default function ChildComponent({attributes}){
    var [pieceOfState, setPieceOfState] = useState('foo');
    var params = useParams(attributes, pieceOfState)
    var set = (name, param) => setParam(name, param, attributes, pieceOfState)

    return (
        <>
            <SomeGrandchildComponent params={params} set={set}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

The three vars in my Child Component (two of which reference outside functions) are reused across all the components in my app, but they're depending on the individual props of each child. I'd like to something like wrapping my child components' content in a provider that contains those three vars just to clean up my child component code a little bit. The problem I'm running into is that then when I try to pass params and set to a grandchild, they show up as undefined, and it makes sense why. Just curious how people would approach this problem, as I'm a little stuck on it.

Comment: I think you are missing the purpose of hooks somewhere. If you prefer the custom hook approach, just move all the logic to it and call anywhere you want but within component. If you need to share data between components, use the provider approach - but then you dont need hooks at all for it.

Comment: @kinduser thanks for this, I get what you're saying. I wasn't thinking about the fact that I can put all the logic in one hook and destructure out the different vars I need into each component. That's what I'll do. Thank you!